# Making the automata diagram still better

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I have drawn an automaton using the tikz library **automata**. I need help in refining the diagram. I am not able to :

1. Align the edge labels (kr, ur, etc.) to the center meaning exactly between two nodes
2. Making equal spacing between the edge labels and the edge
3. Making the diagram look more prettier :) ;)

The LaTeX code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid]
\node[state,initial] (q_0) {$q_0$};
\node[state] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
\node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_0] {$q_2$};
\node[state,accepting] (q_3) [right=of q_1] {$q_3$};
\node[state] (q_4) [right=of q_2] {$q_4$};
\node[state] (q_5) [right=of q_4] {$q_5$};
\node[state,accepting] (q_6) [right=of q_5] {$q_6$};
\path[->] (q_0) edge node[above,align=center]{$kr$} (q_1) edge node[below,align=center]{$ur$} (q_2);
\path[->] (q_1) edge node[above] {$f$} (q_3);
\path[->] (q_2) edge node[above] {$\varepsilon$} (q_4);
\path[->] (q_4) edge node[above] {$\varepsilon$} (q_5);
\path[->] (q_5) edge node[above] {$f$} (q_6);
\path[->] (q_1) edge [loop above] node[above] {$kr$} ();
\path[->] (q_5) edge [bend left] node[below] {$ur$} (q_2);
\path[->] (q_5) edge node[above] {$kr$} (q_1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The screenshot of the diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `align=center` is redundant and make use of `above left` etc instead of simply `above`. With `positioning` library loaded, you can adjust the spaces by yourself (if you want) by `above left = 2mm and 2mm` and `above = 2mm` etc so that they are uniform. I don't suggest this though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid]
\node[state,initial] (q_0) {$q_0$};
\node[state] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
\node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_0] {$q_2$};
\node[state,accepting] (q_3) [right=of q_1] {$q_3$};
\node[state] (q_4) [right=of q_2] {$q_4$};
\node[state] (q_5) [right=of q_4] {$q_5$};
\node[state,accepting] (q_6) [right=of q_5] {$q_6$};
\path[->] (q_0) edge node[above left]{$kr$} (q_1) edge node[below left]{$ur$} (q_2);
\path[->] (q_1) edge node[above] {$f$} (q_3);
\path[->] (q_2) edge node[above] {$\varepsilon$} (q_4);
\path[->] (q_4) edge node[above] {$\varepsilon$} (q_5);
\path[->] (q_5) edge node[above] {$f$} (q_6);
\path[->] (q_1) edge [loop above] node[above] {$kr$} ();
\path[->] (q_5) edge [bend left] node[below] {$ur$} (q_2);
\path[->] (q_5) edge node[above right] {$kr$} (q_1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use `sloped`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid]
\node[state,initial] (q_0) {$q_0$};
\node[state] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
\node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_0] {$q_2$};
\node[state,accepting] (q_3) [right=of q_1] {$q_3$};
\node[state] (q_4) [right=of q_2] {$q_4$};
\node[state] (q_5) [right=of q_4] {$q_5$};
\node[state,accepting] (q_6) [right=of q_5] {$q_6$};
\path[->] (q_0) edge node[above,sloped]{$kr$} (q_1) edge node[below,sloped]{$ur$} (q_2);
\path[->] (q_1) edge node[above] {$f$} (q_3);
\path[->] (q_2) edge node[above] {$\varepsilon$} (q_4);
\path[->] (q_4) edge node[above] {$\varepsilon$} (q_5);
\path[->] (q_5) edge node[above] {$f$} (q_6);
\path[->] (q_1) edge [loop above] node[above] {$kr$} ();
\path[->] (q_5) edge [bend left] node[below] {$ur$} (q_2);
\path[->] (q_5) edge node[above,sloped] {$kr$} (q_1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And at last `prettier` is a relative term as you know.